# ECDH Generating Public key causes the point to not be on the curve VB.net

Tags: vb.net, elliptic-curve, diffie-hellman

I am not sure whether this question was relevant for stackoverflow or cryptography stackexchange, but I thought that I would ask it here as the question might go into programming.

I am trying to generate a public and private keypair using elliptic curve diffie-hellman, I successfully generate a private key that is smaller than the order of the curve but when I calculate the public key by multiplying the base point by the private key I calculate a point that is not on the curve.

The code I am using to generate the keys looks like this:

```
Public Shared Function generate_Keys(ByVal Param As Domain_Parameters) As Keys
        Dim __PrivateKey As BigInteger
        Dim __PublicKey As ECPoint
        Dim d As BigInteger
        Dim rng As New RNGCryptoServiceProvider
        Dim bytes(Param.n.ToByteArray.Length) As Byte
        Do
            rng.GetBytes(bytes)
            d = New BigInteger(bytes)
            If d.Sign = -1 Then
                d = d * -1
            End If
        Loop While d >= Param.n
        __PrivateKey = d
        __PublicKey = Point_Operations.Scalar_Mult(Param.Base, Param, d)
        Dim Ret As Keys
        Ret.PublicKey = __PublicKey
        Ret.PrivateKey = __PrivateKey
        __PrivateKey = BigInteger.Zero()
        d = BigInteger.Zero()
        bytes = {0}
        Return Ret
    End Function
```

And the code that I have tested and works fine to multiply the base point by the private key looks like this:

```
Public Class Point_Operations
''' <summary>
''' A structure that contains data returned from Extended_GCD function
''' </summary>
Friend Structure RetGCD
    Public x As BigInteger
    Public y As BigInteger
    Public GCD As BigInteger
End Structure
''' <summary>
''' Perfomrs addition of two points
''' </summary>
Public Shared Function Addition(ByVal P1 As ECPoint, ByVal P2 As ECPoint) As ECPoint
    'Details about the maths was found on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication
    'Tested with the site http://christelbach.com/ECCalculator.aspx
    If P1.IsPointInfinity() Then
        Return P2
    End If
    If P2.IsPointInfinity() Then
        Return P1
    End If
    If P1.p <> P2.p Then
        Return New ECPoint(-99, -99, -99) 'Add custom errors with ENUM
    End If
    If P1.x = P2.x And P1.y = P2.y Then
        Return New ECPoint(-99, -99, -99)
    End If
    Dim P3 As New ECPoint(P1)
    Dim l, z As BigInteger
    z = Inverse((P2.x - P1.x), P1.p)
    l = ((P2.y - P1.y) * z) Mod P1.p
    P3.x = ((l * l) Mod P1.p - P2.x - P1.x) Mod P1.p
    P3.y = (l * (P1.x - P3.x) Mod P1.p - P1.y) Mod P1.p
    If P3.x < 0 Then 'Tested the code without the peice below and found that the input (10,10,47) and (20,20,47) returned wrong values found out that the difference between each was the prime number so if its less than zero we add the prime whcih seems to work
        P3.x += P1.p
    End If
    If P3.y < 0 Then
        P3.y += P1.p
    End If
    Return P3
End Function
''' <summary>
''' A way of doubling a EC Point
''' </summary>
Public Shared Function PDouble(ByVal P As ECPoint, ByVal a As Domain_Parameters) As ECPoint
    'Details about the maths was found on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication
    'Tested with the site http://christelbach.com/ECCalculator.aspx
    If P.p = 0 And a.Fp.p = 0 Then
        Return New ECPoint(-99, -99, -99)
    End If
    'If a.a = 0 Then
    '    Return New ECPoint(-99, -99, -99)
    'End If
    If P.IsPointInfinity() Then
        Return P
    End If
    Dim prime As BigInteger
    If P.p = 0 Then
        prime = a.Fp.p
    Else
        prime = P.p
    End If
    Dim Q As New ECPoint(P)
    Dim l, z As BigInteger
    z = Inverse(2 * P.y, P.p)
    l = ((((3 * P.x * P.x) Mod P.p + a.a) Mod P.p) * z) Mod P.p
    Q.x = ((l * l) Mod P.p - 2 * P.x) Mod P.p     'accidental set (2 * p.x) to (2 * P.p)
    Q.y = (l * (P.x - Q.x) Mod P.p - P.y) Mod P.p
    If Q.x < 0 Then 'This code was tested and the same problem again with negative values for x and y so we must add the prime to p to correct that
        Q.x += P.p
    End If
    If Q.y < 0 Then
        Q.y += P.p
    End If
    Return Q
End Function
''' <summary>
''' Performs point multiplication with a scalar
''' </summary>
Public Shared Function Scalar_Mult(ByVal P As ECPoint, ByVal a As Domain_Parameters, ByVal Scalar As BigInteger) As ECPoint
    'Details about the maths was found on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication
    'Tested with the site http://christelbach.com/ECCalculator.aspx
    If P.p = 0 And a.Fp.p = 0 Then
        Return New ECPoint(-99, -99, -99)
    End If
    'If a.a = 0 Then
    '    Return New ECPoint(-99, -99, -99)
    'End If
    If P.IsPointInfinity Then
        Return P
    End If
    Dim prime As BigInteger
    If P.p = 0 Then
        prime = a.Fp.p
    Else
        prime = P.p
    End If
    'Dim k As New BigInteger(Scalar.ToByteArray)
    Dim N, S As New ECPoint(P)
    S = New ECPoint(0, 0, prime)                      'Accidentally set S.y = 1 was causing a bad value
    'Dim sc As New BigInteger(k.ToByteArray)        'Depreciated as now we can use bits.lenght
    'Dim bitlenght As Integer
    'While sc / 2 <> 0
    '    bitlenght += 1
    '    sc /= 2
    'End While
    Dim bits As New BitArray(Scalar.ToByteArray)
    For i = 0 To bits.Length - 1
        If bits(i) = True Then                      'Fixed error where BitArray uses True/False instead of 1/0
            S = Addition(S, N)
        End If
        N = PDouble(N, a)
    Next
    Return S
End Function
''' <summary>
''' Calcualtes the Greatest Common Divisor of two numbers
''' </summary>
Private Shared Function Extended_GCD(ByVal a As BigInteger, b As BigInteger) As RetGCD
    'The pseudocode was found on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm#Pseudocode
    'Tested with the site http://planetcalc.com/3298/
    Dim r, o_r As BigInteger
    Dim t, o_t As BigInteger
    Dim s, o_s As BigInteger
    Dim p, q As BigInteger
    Dim ret As RetGCD
    s = 0
    t = 1
    r = b
    o_s = 1
    o_t = 0
    o_r = a
    While r <> 0
        q = o_r / r
        p = r
        r = o_r - q * p
        o_r = p
        p = s
        s = o_s - q * p
        o_s = p
        p = t
        t = o_t - q * p
        o_t = p
    End While
    ret.x = o_s
    ret.y = o_t
    ret.GCD = o_r
    Return ret
End Function
''' <summary>
''' Performs the modular multiplitcative inverse of a number so we can use multiplication instead of division in our arithmetic
''' </summary>
Public Shared Function Inverse(ByVal a As BigInteger, ByVal p As BigInteger) As BigInteger
    'Not tested but works
    Dim ret As RetGCD
    ret = Extended_GCD(a, p)
    If ret.GCD <> 1 Then
        Return 0
    End If
    Return ret.x Mod p
End Function
```

I have a feeling that it is possibly the way I am generating a private key or that I am using the wrong operation when calculating G.d .
Any help would really be appreciated thanks.

**===EDIT===**

After spending some time check values I have found the problem to be caused by the scalar_mult function not returning the right value. Is this function written correctly because i am unsure I have tested it with values from a site and it has been adapted from the pseudocode on wikipedia. Is that the correct method for adding a point to itself x number of time?

Comment: This is way too much code to read through. I did notice the line `If P1.x = P2.x And P1.y = P2.y Then Return New ECPoint(-99, -99, -99)` seems wrong. You want to check if `P1.y = -P2.y` in that compare.

Comment: I have changed the line you suggest. I was wondering if there is a different method to add a base point to itself a number of times?